# find one string in another string in python

Tags: python

i have two list of strings, A and B. I want to find same A in string B.

for example `A=[a12,b13,c24]`; `B=[12,13,25]`.

```
print B[1].find(A[1],1,5)
```

(I want to skip the first character and search from the second)

Comment: Can you provide an expected output of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or code writing service. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Pythin 3.7:

(Sorry for my English, but is not my first language...)

```py
# But A and B elements are not strings like how you want so:
A=["a12","b13","c24"]
B=["12","13","25"]

for b in B:
    for a in A:
        if b in a:
            print(b, "founded in", a)
```

**for b in B:** Mean for every item in B. Will be take it one by one.
**for a in A:** Mean same thing like on B case.
**if b in a:** Mean if item **b** is in item **a** *(if 12 is a12, if 12 is in b13, etc.)*
**print (b, "founded in", a)** I think you all ready know what is doing.

I hope that was helpfully for you...
**P.S.:**
I think the olny difference in this case between Python 3 and 2 is the last line:
From python 3:

```py
print(b, "founded in", a)
```

To python 2:

```py
print b, "founded in", a
```

I'm not so shore, I know just version 3, if I'm wrong some one to correct me...